# Saving html file from server

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public void SaveSofaXML(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(
        Server.MapPath("~/SentinelOperationsUI/SoFaXML.html"));
    string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    streamReader.Close();

    response.StatusCode = 200;
    response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF32;
    response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.html");
    response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
    response.AddHeader("Content-Length", 
        response.ContentEncoding.GetByteCount(text).ToString());
    response.ContentType = "application-download";
}
```

I think im on the right track. But when i try do save the html file (~100kb) the file never finishes downloading. Did i miss some required headers? Thanks

Comment: In the future, please take the time to remove extra indents from your code and add line returns to avoid a horizontal scrollbar. It makes your code much easier to read. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
 Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.html");
 Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/SentinelOperationsUI/SoFaXML.html"));
 Response.End();
```

Comment: +1 `TransmitFile` was made for this purpose and works well.  Why re-invent the wheel?